# Question in elementary of vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Good morning.

I have some question in vector space.

if $S$ is a vector space, and also $W$ is an vector space over GF(2).we define 
$$S=W=\langle  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1
\end{pmatrix}\rangle  $$
where $\langle \rangle$ is an span.
also the two vectors

$$
wx=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and
$$
st=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0
\end{pmatrix}
.$$ 
 Why $S\not \subset \langle wx\rangle$ and $W\not \subset \langle st\rangle$.
why $st$ and $wx$ are not linear independent.
Can any one give me the content of (vectors in) $S$ , $W$ ,and   $\langle u(wx)\rangle$.
When tow vectors $v_1,v_2\in V\in V$ where $V$ is an vector space, then what is the result of $v_1v_2$, is it vector or scalar in vector space.

I hope that I found the answer ,for my question because now I am reading paper about Network coding and it demands a lot of vector space, and exusmer for my English, Thanks.

Comment: The notation is very confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by "$u=(s)$ is a vector space"?

Comment: The question makes no sense mathematically, because your question asks something about $u(s)$, but you did not define what $u(s)$ is.

Comment: What does $(s)$ mean? What is $s$? What is the function $(.)$?

Comment: s is vector space and w vector space ,wx and st are vectors

Comment: ok i will explain, in reality the problem we have a graph and u s w x are vertices in the graph and wx and st are edges,ok we need to each vertex assigned a vector space and each edge outgoing from vetrix assigned a vector so all the edges in the graph have vectors linear independent, for now i have some problem in the above definition.

Comment: @MokhTarBou And what is $u(s)$? Also, usually, we denote vector spaces with **capital** letters because they are sets. If you want any help with this question, you will **need** to improve your question, because right now we have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @MokhTarBou Also, don't add *vital* parts of the quesiton in the comments. Edit your question, and make it readable.

Comment: I have edit now.

Comment: Another think,the are vector over $GF(2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why $S\not \subset \langle wx\rangle$

Because $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1
\end{pmatrix}$ is an element of $S$, but it is not an element of $\langle wx\rangle$

> and $W\not \subset \langle st\rangle$.

This is the same question as before, since $S=W$ and $wx=st$. It's just a relabeling. (like the question "does the Earth orbit the Sun" is the same question as "does our planet orbit our nearest star"

---

> Why $st$ and $wx$ are not linear independent.

Because $1\cdot st + (-1)\cdot wx = 0$, which means that there exists a nontrivial linear combination of the two vectors that is $0$.

---

> Can any one give me the content of (vectors in) $S$ , $W$ ,and   $\langle u(wx)\rangle$.

$S=W=\mathbb R^2$, I don't know what $u(wx)$ is because it is not defined.

---

> When tow (probably **two**) vectors $v_1,v_2\in V\in V$ where $V$ is an vector space, then what is the result of $v_1v_2$, is it vector or scalar in vector space.

Multiplication of vectors is not defined. However, you can say you are talking about the dot product, in which case the result is a scalar.

Comment: but $\langle wx \rangle$ is span,dose not containt only one vector,for example if $\langle wx \rangle$ over $GF(2)$ can we say that the span contain all vectors $\alpha \times wx$ and $\alpha =\{0,1\}$.am i right ?

Comment: @MokhTarBou Sure, $\langle wx\rangle$ is a span, but it still does not include $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. It's easy to show that.

Comment: ok we can conclude that if we have a span $ \langle wx \rangle
$ and vector space $S$  containt vector$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1
\end{pmatrix}$ and this vector not in the span then $ S \not  \subset  \langle wx \rangle $.

Comment: Then how we do the product of two vector in vector space?

Comment: @MokhTarBou No offense, but what you need is a course in basic linear algebra...

Comment: yes i am new in linear algebra but thank you